# Get last occurance in a <DIV>

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
    $('span .breadcrumb').each(function(){
        $('#footer').addClass($(this).text());
    });
});
```

So it reads the .breadcrumb and adds the text contained with text to #footer.

However .breadcrumb occurs a number of time with in the breadcrumb navigation, I want it to read just the second value with the class .breadcrumb - Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last one:

```
 $("span .breadcrumb:last")
```

Second one:

```
 $("span .breadcrumb:eq(1)")
```